# How to remove last " |, \, . " icons in wp_nav_menu(); on from a website menus?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How I remove `{\|,}` icons after last menu item in frontend of `wp_nav_menu();` in WordPress

````
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' 
  => 'd-flex flex-row-reverse', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'top-menu 
  top-menu-links', 'menu_id' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '<span> | 
  </span>', 'theme_location' => 'primary', ) ```
````

Comment: Kindly share your code as well

Comment: <?php         wp_nav_menu(
          array(
           'menu'            => '',
                 'container'       => 'div',
                 'container_class' => 'd-flex flex-row-reverse',
                 'container_id'    => '',
                 'menu_class'      => 'top-menu top-menu-links',
                 'menu_id'         => '',
                 'link_before'     => '',
                 'link_after'      => '<span>  |</span>',
                 'theme_location'  => 'primary',
          )

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this css class.

```
.top-menu-links li:last:child a span{
display:none;
}
```